# Arcpy - LayerList - Count/Length

Tags: arcpy, layers, length, list, count

I use arcpy to load all layers in the current map document, and I need all layers but not the last one (this is my layer for the symbology template).

How can I access the length or count of the layer list or another way to exclude the last layer?

I already tried to use length and count, but it did not work.

My code so far:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for lyr in lyrList:
    #for each layer, but not the last one
    #do something
```

Comment: This question applies equally to lists created without reference to ArcPy and so is a pure Python question to which an answer should be easy to find at [so]..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may simply use the `len`-funtion:

```
lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
num = len(lyrList)
```

If you want to loop all the layers except the last one use:

```
lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[:-1]
```

Comment: perfect, thanks :) Now I saw, it would also work this way to exclude the last layer from the layer list: lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[:-1]